# Python - why is method 2 (nested while loops) faster than method 1 (for, while loops)?

Tags: python

I'm working my way through the Project Euler questions and am testing out two approaches to computing the prime factors of a number. Repetition within the list of factors is fine.

Both approaches are very similar but the second (with nested while loops) is much, much faster than the first. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks in advance

```
def prime_factors_1(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    factors = []
    for d in range(2, n):
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
    return factors


def prime_factors_2(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d += 1
    return factors
```

Comment: Is this Python 2? For large values of `n`, `range(2, n)` is creating a very big list - try `xrange` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the number of steps either method would take:

- the `range()` is precomputed so you *will* loop over `n - 2` divisor candidates. Reducing `n` in the loop (via the `/=` augmented division operator) will not influence the number of iterations.
- the `while` loop will loop over far fever candidate divisors, as `n` is lowered with each divisor found, resulting in fewer iterations.

Say `n` is 100. For the `for` loop that means there **will** be 98 iterations. But for the `while` loop, you get:

1. `while 100 > 1` is true, `100 % 2 == 0` is true, so `n /= 2` reduces this to 50. Then to 25, then `d` is incremented to 3 and the next iteration starts.
2. `while 25 > 1`, is true, `25 % 3 == 0` is false, so `d` is incremented to `4`
3. `while 25 > 1`, is true, `25 % 4 == 0` is false, so `d` is incremented to `5`
4. `while 25 > 1`, is true, `25 % 5 == 0` is true, so `n /= 5` reduces `n` to `5`, then `1`.

In *just 4 steps* of the outer loop you have determined the divisors. 4 << 98.

Comment: Voting this one up, too.

Answer (score -1):

If you use python2, the following line makes the difference (in the 1st method):

```
for d in range(2, n):
```

`range()` in Python2 creates a whole list of numbers and for large values of n this can represent a significant overhead. It is thus better to use `xrange()` which returns an *iterator* - an object that knows how to yield values one by one as needed, without having to create them all in advance and holding them in memory.

Comment: This is just a *small* difference. Even with xrange the `while` loop blows the timings out of the water.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using Python 3 so I knew range() is doing the equivalent of xrange() in Python 2

Comment: Jumped too quickly to a conclusion when I saw `range()` instead of its `x` counterpart, and missed the elephant in the room. My bad.